# React Navigation with Redux - StackNavigator Load Other Screen Content in Background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

What is the best way to show a splash screen while content loads in the backround with React Native, React Navigation, and Redux?

I currently have a Stack Navigator  that Contains:

- an initial Splash Screen (*SplashScreen*)
- a nested Tab Navigator with Content (*AppNavigator*).

---

```
export const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Splash: { screen: SplashScreen },
    App: { screen: AppNavigator },
}, {
    navigationOptions: { header: null},
});
```

The nested Tab Navigator (*AppNavigator*), has multiple screens that load content from a React Native *WebView* component.

I want the Splash Screen to appear while the *WebView* components load content from various uri's. The plan was to dispatch an action with Redux using the *onLoadStart* and *onLoad* methods of the *WebView* components to trigger a navigation *reset* action to the *AppNavigator*.

Navigation Between the Splash Screen and the main App work fine but none of the content from the main App loads while the splash screen is up and the route doesn't appear in the navigation state.

What is the best way to get that content to load?

---

Redux Reducer for Navigation:

```
const initialNavState = RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
   NavigationActions.init()
);

function NavigationReducer(state = initialNavState, action) {
    let nextState = RootNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return nextState || state;
}
```

`initialNavState` at runtime:

```
{
    index:0
    routes:
        Array(1)
            0:{routeName: "Splash", key: "Init-id-1504353614126-0"}
}
```

Comment: I would use states to update UI. Set an initial state loading: true, and render activityIndicator until loading is set to false.

Comment: I have the same question! Would love an answer. @eden Your answer would work except it doesn't solve the main issue: getting a webview which is not yet mounted to begin loading

Comment: Yes, thats why webview has its own ‘renderLoading’ prop. You can also achieve that by using a Modal component.